# Office Online Server performance testing

Tags: office365, performance-testing

We are testing an application that uses Office Online Server for Word document editing and we would like to ensure that our Office Online machines will be able to handle whatever load we are going to have.

But there is a problem. When we inspect the requests that are going through to Office Online server we can't figure out how are they constructed. We can run the same requests with changed revision Id and it adds a symbol to the document but it stops working the next day (all the cookies are refreshed on every test run).

I'm looking for an advice on how to construct the request that will add a symbol to the start or end of the document.